# Combining "bool" and "terms" query in ElasticSearch v6.2 (on AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am trying to debug an ElasticSearch query and I could use some help with figuring out what I am doing wrong here.

The problem I am having is when I add a "terms" query on a field, no hits are found when I expect results back.

This is the query WITHOUT the "terms" part:

```
GET /activity/doc/_search
{
      "query":{  
         "bool":{  
            "must": [
               {
                 "range": {
                   "ageMax": {
                     "gte": 20
                   }
                 }
               },
               {
                 "range": {
                   "ageMin": {
                     "lte": 28
                   }
                 }
               },
               {  
                  "range":{  
                     "activityDate":{  
                        "gte":"2019-06-12T16:23:12.709Z"
                     }
                  }
               },
              {  
               "geo_distance":{  
                  "distance":"50.0km",
                  "location.gps":{  
                     "lon":-122.406417,
                     "lat":37.785834
                  }
               }
              }
            ]
         }

      }
   }
```

This is the result I get back:

```
{
  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 4,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "activity",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "f35980fe-94cb-4c4a-9ee7-84dbace823b0",
        "_score": 4,
        "_source": {
          "ageMax": 68,
          "__typename": "Activity",
          "photo": {
            "bucket": "vevivo8106a3b4577d41ec943f5ff2d7536d38-develop",
            "region": "eu-west-1",
            "Key": "Facebook_137538237374224/FA5A7B52-48E6-4816-85FD-06AD04721FBF.jpg",
            "url": "https://vevivo8106a3b4577d41ec943f5ff2d7536d38-develop.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/public/Facebook_137538237374224/FA5A7B52-48E6-4816-85FD-06AD04721FBF.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQUVMMI25HVHW4O5W%2F20190611%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190611T202205Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Security-Token=AgoGb3JpZ2luENj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCWV1LXdlc3QtMSKAAoIYw2UKtl9sRiRSxJ6OpnAhQ1GT4WfSzCWQybWB1ufO%2BGUTP4GFNuB7nmq5Y3wOvhmGdMbCY54Do5GGA1GpW3c0OzUtzu%2FKm5AreF8gLSwcqYBoVCiiPlEHhsJ%2FUINKCdwcFp%2BNWs5czT%2Fj%2BrPa8yqBkQxVbxAc%2BoMxadBhvARlPoYcqdR25vnbaoDewiS%2BFE7UjbvF0HvLcu8G2S6Dgy9r1w0tnZIzj512WsOwj0AsM5MFr7ut1xUdOuyJq8sC4BV8xa8FR7VKFEdYpYJyfId%2B0sTQZcv%2FbOHKDCvdRTvDtzez3GXj6nrEon5mRG81cJdYlRMRWaoEBvbG1Mn0pesqrwUIrf%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARACGgwwNDQzODQ5Mjk0NjYiDG%2FxkEMhjuwECcH1%2FyqDBUf9AxuOCXR%2B5MtZfA%2BceNx7gzsai7LmfFpPQcYqd0xv5M0VzkUiPCD5wUP417qDzX5KC9Zft%2BX9C2RKYJoxd0%2Bav%2BsQoN62Mld0wuDRykISJTd5Qknq8FFvWKznD%2BTh2jr%2BWD2LYwhw3gt07p9LZwi9BKV67ktzo5rK77XTLfCFKDZBDiyEUWyrBea1%2BZt45p%2F5O6S7D7yxW0GFYXXrwLfbg2FGJikXDVwmcHnw5s8oh6b9UFNJUZzqllXYA7Tg8S0nkixZuu1O4OBU6mht7YhPng2%2FZLy0k%2FyoaLggHc3lbPpQJYSj1XIXqbZlbS5wSKZyivkUuBJAMFNLcRgj%2BpA0TYCGTwF2zZgxwvWm3H%2B7NDvH%2FrnQajW7ANna6HhS1WZ4fEtnFWNWxArjCJoQk5hQPnkyWyeQda9aAMBDr72hhRTw8PTZkim6nSKxwM4UnQ4jElopt0UbXSKQxusZJFo%2F0UZAgdWg00TdjIgVs3q%2BZ9CMS5jt%2BTbatrCDWDIXKIEuMrqqKanrPDfq60hV0I2BP8poTGT3RczVE7tbfeMLui3E5jGvP9xkoCZfWt9GXZvQWTXinilVonPkHRVGa7sqhygcYh9TmhO18eKiBk7mwO1cwIKlRfTZJBr%2F1xu3IP7oKBG8AOwjSJJx0fDpRLUMCWH%2BC%2BHNiAqjRpShCvX3OFOFRygMa50C0ocdlGrEtKDZBXa2%2BSW4WR0LEeozMeWjJTPF9iA%2FE8GyCscdnx2bMAhccJupAplL7UhCMTdRCJ2SalnNJR7Q49LvG4ryG8OdxhhYZD4n51wVVWlB7fqsP%2Bki8feH77jokiofq3eOU9jFk3SaxbfkzB8%2FcVhtzCrS%2BSswvZaA6AU%3D&X-Amz-Signature=399ae23fe3f01338d1bf79b918c9ce51ffa91c8f705d62ea3b516b0341b60578&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host"
          },
          "dateModified": "2019-06-11T20:21:52.870Z",
          "version": 1,
          "usersWatching": 0,
          "createdAt": "2019-06-11T20:22:43.215Z",
          "likesCount": 0,
          "textData": "Watch a dance movie?",
          "enrolledUsers": 0,
          "activityDate": "2019-06-19T20:12:44.000Z",
          "ageMin": 18,
          "dateCreated": "2019-06-11T20:21:52.870Z",
          "peopleRequested": 2,
          "commentsCount": 0,
          "location": {
            "address": {
              "zipcode": "94108",
              "country": "United States",
              "city": "San Francisco",
              "street": "Stockton St",
              "state": null
            },
            "gps": {
              "lon": -122.406417,
              "lat": 37.785834
            }
          },
          "enrollmentRequests": 0,
          "id": "f35980fe-94cb-4c4a-9ee7-84dbace823b0",
          "activityCreatorId": "Facebook_137538237374224",
          "category": "Movies::Ballet",
          "updatedAt": "2019-06-11T20:22:43.215Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "activity",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "ce9ab1ee-8fa8-42dd-aeb8-c1a9f58ab6b3",
        "_score": 4,
        "_source": {
          "ageMax": 68,
          "__typename": "Activity",
          "photo": {
            "bucket": "vevivo8106a3b4577d41ec943f5ff2d7536d38-develop",
            "region": "eu-west-1",
            "Key": "Facebook_137538237374224/FF8E51D9-279B-4EC2-9461-55E2CBFC637A.jpg",
            "url": "https://vevivo8106a3b4577d41ec943f5ff2d7536d38-develop.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/public/Facebook_137538237374224/FF8E51D9-279B-4EC2-9461-55E2CBFC637A.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQUVMMI25F4QOD3PE%2F20190611%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190611T203152Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Security-Token=AgoGb3JpZ2luENj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCWV1LXdlc3QtMSKAAhy6dUpwqL9847F4NppRj%2FsFwXtJgJQk%2BK6fsSlAzfUwJGEXEDhGrOEs45HiOpHAEN5YoEskPEb6YpfUdLpXanO5TaYp%2F4Q4uiMMTcR9PVPg%2BVFUylTYJQ%2BskQDcqJw%2BPqppZiWvMMEzJNkB335B6gyqLgsJWyl0okgKLknVVKTJAntsGiqfX%2FvVFk94aoMP0Ubv3ymXyxZ9dxqA5Mqe6EbNoxteQMdLQqoZPfXiGQmvDjgfpZph2SCkkOSwp1slGF0vCjOIztj%2B4Rsfq9jfI14Ks6th25SHOZjeB0HEx497KgFyYQFp41ke8u4WsJ91alv8fGpyMhId2b8v%2F%2BwkNsgqrwUIrv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARACGgwwNDQzODQ5Mjk0NjYiDOiqDscm7ZoQvO8lWCqDBZB56K6XqJ565o1bnZc%2Bh5x9JHeAU8kOcaDvSfa8syzOCQTSW%2BORfmPJzKDij5DN%2B4QFSvycY%2BuU%2FTQqfB6F3bbfD8rLr1HsVBFaKzwIOA6RSEDolCJb3Q2ZyazfFPuzOof3BlEFKYrUoqO1x5Ur0K3z8DRsst7TyAMBPxiYnN%2BZMzsxjFXRz7ps24suwvO3Urz0zogJWGP%2FxSvX%2F6386bTo8X9oIPAVhwdjEebzYATCfe02IRPUxXGQHyZ3qVF5Ccy7zioLW2iNVUQawCN26lfcoUq79xt%2F9mygFM36Xyr3cC0EH5dV5hIj6f%2F9GDvjb%2FLex0c3XPBtzgDDdJoLPgU4UFdIyhYlHNrUZN40vpLZqJIBKQkjyUcoSkzW0dhCx0DukjimLScwwUPxEtSb%2BKqk94zbsZUJjnSBzcGf2DjbCYbDs5EZqg0pm8iVCFtAJODIDLktwZUhl%2BCrv9JYv8epzQgIBDBUIPjeudOMLodahv%2BfFwHl9lRLNUZkDPGgmhIby62J5y2pkoJE353mKPs%2BDvqkmqTMy2377DH1IOsrPRmkgWldPpv4uFD5jKN3r9xxQv4LUswzD%2FfPSBG2pgvaUgeE2YcWg3o6CcW4KtUOPLucHLw66lkgcnQ8M9feo3j35z%2B9lSblNTd6rCuVgrxa9zuRzNxpRl37ZSut%2B7VPy%2FcKN05mHsZfvIBVcPXF4SdQwgnH2%2BZz4fNEU75MRLyqud7rKQ47h2pamKL%2F%2BUqPn8tNlAAZNMpQHh1KAyIrE35WBbIMgAZSVRUeXcvHVONTJrMbeVC%2FZ0EYAfnCR8uxBsGWPIcsObXN%2FJAGbLGcMW5QB%2Bu1MTSI0qbLoxtzxK9r9lQwzZ6A6AU%3D&X-Amz-Signature=5bdfec0ae588f234af3f8e6dd75c3c7ed8f85fdb3c333c895d02c6f63bf0a548&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host"
          },
          "dateModified": "2019-06-11T20:31:31.646Z",
          "version": 1,
          "usersWatching": 0,
          "createdAt": "2019-06-11T20:32:51.687Z",
          "likesCount": 0,
          "textData": "Anyone for a dance movie?",
          "enrolledUsers": 0,
          "activityDate": "2019-06-21T20:31:23.000Z",
          "ageMin": 18,
          "dateCreated": "2019-06-11T20:31:31.646Z",
          "peopleRequested": 2,
          "commentsCount": 0,
          "location": {
            "address": {
              "zipcode": "94108",
              "country": "United States",
              "city": "San Francisco",
              "street": "Stockton St",
              "state": null
            },
            "gps": {
              "lon": -122.406417,
              "lat": 37.785834
            }
          },
          "enrollmentRequests": 0,
          "id": "ce9ab1ee-8fa8-42dd-aeb8-c1a9f58ab6b3",
          "activityCreatorId": "Facebook_137538237374224",
          "category": "Movies::Romance",
          "updatedAt": "2019-06-11T20:32:51.687Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "activity",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "309db646-903c-471e-b045-b1f55ae6cff0",
        "_score": 4,
        "_source": {
          "ageMax": 68,
          "__typename": "Activity",
          "photo": {
            "bucket": "vevivo8106a3b4577d41ec943f5ff2d7536d38-develop",
            "region": "eu-west-1",
            "Key": "Facebook_137538237374224/18BB874D-F59C-4924-8764-75A25020C61C.jpg",
            "url": "https://vevivo8106a3b4577d41ec943f5ff2d7536d38-develop.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/public/Facebook_137538237374224/18BB874D-F59C-4924-8764-75A25020C61C.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQUVMMI25F4QOD3PE%2F20190611%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190611T203026Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Security-Token=AgoGb3JpZ2luENj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCWV1LXdlc3QtMSKAAhy6dUpwqL9847F4NppRj%2FsFwXtJgJQk%2BK6fsSlAzfUwJGEXEDhGrOEs45HiOpHAEN5YoEskPEb6YpfUdLpXanO5TaYp%2F4Q4uiMMTcR9PVPg%2BVFUylTYJQ%2BskQDcqJw%2BPqppZiWvMMEzJNkB335B6gyqLgsJWyl0okgKLknVVKTJAntsGiqfX%2FvVFk94aoMP0Ubv3ymXyxZ9dxqA5Mqe6EbNoxteQMdLQqoZPfXiGQmvDjgfpZph2SCkkOSwp1slGF0vCjOIztj%2B4Rsfq9jfI14Ks6th25SHOZjeB0HEx497KgFyYQFp41ke8u4WsJ91alv8fGpyMhId2b8v%2F%2BwkNsgqrwUIrv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARACGgwwNDQzODQ5Mjk0NjYiDOiqDscm7ZoQvO8lWCqDBZB56K6XqJ565o1bnZc%2Bh5x9JHeAU8kOcaDvSfa8syzOCQTSW%2BORfmPJzKDij5DN%2B4QFSvycY%2BuU%2FTQqfB6F3bbfD8rLr1HsVBFaKzwIOA6RSEDolCJb3Q2ZyazfFPuzOof3BlEFKYrUoqO1x5Ur0K3z8DRsst7TyAMBPxiYnN%2BZMzsxjFXRz7ps24suwvO3Urz0zogJWGP%2FxSvX%2F6386bTo8X9oIPAVhwdjEebzYATCfe02IRPUxXGQHyZ3qVF5Ccy7zioLW2iNVUQawCN26lfcoUq79xt%2F9mygFM36Xyr3cC0EH5dV5hIj6f%2F9GDvjb%2FLex0c3XPBtzgDDdJoLPgU4UFdIyhYlHNrUZN40vpLZqJIBKQkjyUcoSkzW0dhCx0DukjimLScwwUPxEtSb%2BKqk94zbsZUJjnSBzcGf2DjbCYbDs5EZqg0pm8iVCFtAJODIDLktwZUhl%2BCrv9JYv8epzQgIBDBUIPjeudOMLodahv%2BfFwHl9lRLNUZkDPGgmhIby62J5y2pkoJE353mKPs%2BDvqkmqTMy2377DH1IOsrPRmkgWldPpv4uFD5jKN3r9xxQv4LUswzD%2FfPSBG2pgvaUgeE2YcWg3o6CcW4KtUOPLucHLw66lkgcnQ8M9feo3j35z%2B9lSblNTd6rCuVgrxa9zuRzNxpRl37ZSut%2B7VPy%2FcKN05mHsZfvIBVcPXF4SdQwgnH2%2BZz4fNEU75MRLyqud7rKQ47h2pamKL%2F%2BUqPn8tNlAAZNMpQHh1KAyIrE35WBbIMgAZSVRUeXcvHVONTJrMbeVC%2FZ0EYAfnCR8uxBsGWPIcsObXN%2FJAGbLGcMW5QB%2Bu1MTSI0qbLoxtzxK9r9lQwzZ6A6AU%3D&X-Amz-Signature=5c5f8e0237e7dc3725617a82db97dfd37c87fe3872a85eabb883100f41aa26e1&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host"
          },
          "dateModified": "2019-06-11T20:30:14.449Z",
          "version": 1,
          "usersWatching": 0,
          "createdAt": "2019-06-11T20:31:25.613Z",
          "likesCount": 0,
          "textData": "Romance Movie Anyone?",
          "enrolledUsers": 0,
          "activityDate": "2019-06-14T20:31:17.000Z",
          "ageMin": 18,
          "dateCreated": "2019-06-11T20:30:14.449Z",
          "peopleRequested": 1,
          "commentsCount": 0,
          "location": {
            "address": {
              "zipcode": "94108",
              "country": "United States",
              "city": "San Francisco",
              "street": "Stockton St",
              "state": null
            },
            "gps": {
              "lon": -122.406417,
              "lat": 37.785834
            }
          },
          "enrollmentRequests": 0,
          "id": "309db646-903c-471e-b045-b1f55ae6cff0",
          "activityCreatorId": "Facebook_137538237374224",
          "category": "Movies::Romance",
          "updatedAt": "2019-06-11T20:31:25.613Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "activity",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "3a7c629e-803d-4fb9-8b7c-5fac08255649",
        "_score": 4,
        "_source": {
          "ageMax": 62,
          "__typename": "Activity",
          "photo": {
            "bucket": "vevivo8106a3b4577d41ec943f5ff2d7536d38-develop",
            "region": "eu-west-1",
            "Key": "d70053b2-cbf2-47ea-959e-6b081e00dac9/ECEFB5DB-0F32-4142-A26C-10B7ED120452.jpg",
            "url": "https://vevivo8106a3b4577d41ec943f5ff2d7536d38-develop.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/public/d70053b2-cbf2-47ea-959e-6b081e00dac9/ECEFB5DB-0F32-4142-A26C-10B7ED120452.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQUVMMI25EVY5X32Z%2F20190612%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190612T125107Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Security-Token=AgoGb3JpZ2luEOn%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCWV1LXdlc3QtMSKAAhT4eq9r4GURlO%2B6hQW0PAMKVmFBUtHaI14%2Fz3i0p3WBjCHnlT49PoOXHaUgZKUVWqDQYKsSWthth%2FfV5k%2BRN76Nce%2BZKNfa9Gzpy%2BCUHVY34koYZSPo%2FFLC%2Be5ox3RBBgrpkB%2BzPHkuc4KNyPKIoSr%2BOHolUhRMZIOmRL84lzzttazBpgwIqxacKo6DQha2k%2FJTh5v%2FqDUXxLwr8Bj0DMRVx7PZg4MxLFSAZ0lShUa7H%2BpHKxkA%2F9wFcTPCK32HuvAub32O1qn1N8zBJxqZhLa5YtBA0vydq%2BIUHPsYePDryc0jTmz4MNVcQsrTPddOPkDoD1qX%2BI1pXEStBPV3EPkqrwUIvv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARACGgwwNDQzODQ5Mjk0NjYiDDCSdZ%2BxIQDybtgqASqDBQC%2BvI1sG5B9CqFZNNSl9qiRMnqbvQJ3WU57qsiz4kJftgMBU0nMdhl97p6mDXhJBvqC2vTgnnGiTbrRMr7%2BvNbNzbigkUO0exM%2B7bqxt6ij%2B8gz%2FdLd8T5Faj8j6AzvKGtwHxaGvaG0tCxvJGD%2BNYzOJxS8mae%2Fvf6qgpH%2BzQaf057NaZ9KsNlFZfCDD2CpBT%2FmB05tnzPmLDy5amzyuCyLWZgi7fzB6mqcKBmN0DktWb6RPRyaNFFi6PaJwHIDF%2BL1B3jx%2BmOXMon2Xwki8j9WugGWhQvMAl%2Fug82QoX1bxHegymeesIG052D6e%2F5XieeDwUZZ5IQinTx3eqs3m%2BqFlkxdIRb3JoPRldVm8hNUHG59mEI01r16%2B5SjTJ%2B4yvVR3x2%2BkGV2DY%2FjV5K8PueUHsIlN2hMGepG%2F7Rwg5fMdgg0YX3zEHZuyVdGvcQtXJbpmpYXxsXmRBkhIt3n59%2FtypAKHP1yLzV2Gxp2aYwUGiDVvn%2BsPHlfFL2FM4eil8g6%2FQVmSjZlw3Wa9Ke5HhIq5RV8la4TyOa7ogoAmoiVTlvqNvYgWlWrxl9zij4MgNwZ3S5Z79svhUNS8zHPDCtHru%2FXj81AUaTDsFSU%2BcVH%2BfKZuYVp3xWFAMSWhD3RQ5RT%2B8zCSKfvcI7hnI2i%2BhvAFFdqD8yPKBQ0A17LyYBc%2FAG91JDvw8lOM8fbmHQiMcmnd62V%2FE9RoQ0OAf3mrobMulrwxLKoQd%2F%2F9Hf8G7fVZZFP5jnIDVkIZScY8pZkzjYgftscGjagStFm4UtjM3KKWkBW5kb3zQREEFl9lUNrna4I89rVwxGxHcj0yVso18If2VPv932VzI2b455B2cbLGnswh%2BqD6AU%3D&X-Amz-Signature=72ac408bd3e51780c2ce3a44843365ca70550d07e0d7eb1e8781968ca5bf854e&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host"
          },
          "dateModified": "2019-06-12T12:50:51.986Z",
          "version": 1,
          "usersWatching": 0,
          "createdAt": "2019-06-12T12:52:28.461Z",
          "likesCount": 0,
          "textData": "Movie night?",
          "enrolledUsers": 0,
          "activityDate": "2019-06-14T12:50:14.000Z",
          "ageMin": 18,
          "dateCreated": "2019-06-12T12:50:51.986Z",
          "peopleRequested": 1,
          "commentsCount": 0,
          "location": {
            "address": {
              "zipcode": "94108",
              "country": "United States",
              "city": "San Francisco",
              "street": "Stockton St",
              "state": null
            },
            "gps": {
              "lon": -122.406417,
              "lat": 37.785834
            }
          },
          "enrollmentRequests": 0,
          "id": "3a7c629e-803d-4fb9-8b7c-5fac08255649",
          "activityCreatorId": "d70053b2-cbf2-47ea-959e-6b081e00dac9",
          "category": "Movies::Ballet",
          "updatedAt": "2019-06-12T12:52:28.461Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I add the "terms" query in the filter like this:

```
GET /activity/doc/_search
{

      "query":{  
         "bool":{  
            "must": [
               {
                 "range": {
                   "ageMax": {
                     "gte": 20
                   }
                 }
               },
               {
                 "range": {
                   "ageMin": {
                     "lte": 28
                   }
                 }
               },
               {  
                  "range":{  
                     "activityDate":{  
                        "gte":"2019-06-12T16:23:12.709Z"
                     }
                  }
               },
              {  
               "geo_distance":{  
                  "distance":"50.0km",
                  "location.gps":{  
                     "lon":-122.406417,
                     "lat":37.785834
                  }
               }
              }
            ],
            "filter": {
              "terms": 
              {
                "category": ["Movies::Ballet"]
              }
            }
         }

      }
   }
```

I expect to get back only the documents with category 'Movies::Ballet' but I get no hits..

I tried adding the "terms" query to the "must" array but same result.

I appreciate any help with figuring out where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get the query I want to work by changing 2 things:

1. Changed the category field for my test records to "Movies_Ballet" instead of "Movies::Ballet".  I guess the "::" is a special character I was not aware of (someone please correct me if I am wrong here)
2. Changed the terms query to lowercase like:

   "filter":  {
             "terms": {
               "category": [
                 "movies_romance",
                 "TWO"
               ]
             }

The expected result is returned.
hope this helps someone save some time